# Posting device_id through request headers in django rest framework api

Tags: python, django, api, request, django-rest-framework

I am trying to post device_id through request headers below is my code but i am not getting able to post it. i am sending device_id through headers in postman.

Plz Avoid the spacing

views.py

```
class DeviceID(APIView):
def post(self, request):
    device_id = request.META.get('HTTP_X_DEVICE', '')
    serializer = DeviceSerializer(data=device_id)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
    else:
        return Response(serializer.errors)
```

serializers.py

```
class DeviceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
DEVICE = serializers.IntegerField()

class Meta:
    model = Device
    fields = 'DEVICE'

def create(self, validated_data):
    return Device.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

models.py

```
class Device(models.Model):
    DEVICE = models.IntegerField()
```

urls.py

```
  url(r'^device/', views.DeviceID.as_view()),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The serializer expects a dictionary for data. Change the serializer instantiation to:

```
serializer = DeviceSerializer(data={'DEVICE': device_id})
```

Comment: Thanks this was accurate

Comment: can u tell me how to include this device id in with my request.data and pass it in serializer.  this is the code                                        device_id = request.META.get('HTTP_DEVICE', '')
serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data)

Answer (score 0):

Serialiser 'fields' should be a list. Right now the serializer is expecting fields ('D', 'E', 'V', 'I', 'C', 'E') - so the serializer is ignoring the DEVICE value it received. Instead do ('DEVICE' ,)

Data passed in the serializer must be a dictionary.

What header name are you using in postman? Django prefixes HTTP_ to all headers - even ones that already start with HTTP_

You don't need to explicitly define the DEVICE field as an IntegerField on the serialzer. ModelSerializers infer the field type from the mode.

You do not need to specify 'create' on the ModelSerializer. It's handled for you already.

Instead of doing `return Response(errors)`, you can do `serialzer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)` and the framework will automatically return a 400 response code with the serializer errors.

End the URL patterns with $ otherwise unwanted side effects happen such as /device/ghhgfffghjnfrrdxc routing to your view, instead of 404ing.

Comment: I changed my code and now I am using 'HTTP_X_HEADER_DEVICE' in my code and in postman in headers but it is giving this error        {
  "DEVICE": [
    "A valid integer is required."
  ]
}

Comment: what value are you using for the header called "HEADER_DEVICE"? I assume it's a valid integer?

Comment: i am using a valid integer . i tried to test it by passing no value and it is still showing the same error. my code is same as above and i made the changes like passing a dictionary